# difference between binding click and binding keypress to an input field

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent users from moving the cursor around inside the focused input field. Don't worry, this will only be until they begin replacing the default value with one of their own!

The following code successfully prevents the user from moving the cursor with the arrow keys:

```
$('.test').focus(function() {
    $(this).bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode > 36 && event.keyCode < 41) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true; 
        }      
    });
});
```

But similar code such as :

```
$('.test').focus(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', false);
});
```

does not stop the clicks from moving the cursor inside the input field. 
What is the difference between these two scenarios?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Yes. That would be easier. I think I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`keypress` is an event fired when an input was done via the keyboard. `click` is a mouse event.

Comment: hmm. I just tried mousedown, which works, but click still does not work. Why would mousedown work and click not work?

Comment: @cowabungabill `mousedown` is fired, when you press down the mouse button. `click` is fired, when you release the mouse button. `click` is the same as `mousedown` and `mouseup` combined.

Comment: Use both if you need to 'mousedown click'

Comment: right. i didn't realize the cursor moves on mousedown, but it makes sense when you think about the fact that selecting text is possible. oops! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go man...

```
$('#noclick').on('mousedown click', function() {
          return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqSzF/2/)

Comment: `return false;` does not stop the events default action. You will need a `function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); }` as your callback. See: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Yes, an `event.preventDefault();` does disable the normal event action for the selected event. That means no action will be executed by the browser, unless you add your own code after `event.preventDefault();` to perform any action on the click by yourself. For example, `$('[href]').on('mousedown click', function() { event.preventDefault(); });` disables all hyper-links on the current page.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks man. Though maybe you wouldn't want to prevent the initial click so you could at least gain focus on an input?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works for you:

```
$(".test").focus();
$(".test").bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode > 36 && event.keyCode < 41) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true; 
    }      
});
$(".test").bind('mousedown', function(event) {
    return false;
});​
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/zEp36/

This prevents all mouse down actions on the input field. The arrow keys are also suppressed. Just start typing and you will replace the default value.